# Hatcher's exercise 0.26 - topological concern

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, exercise 0.26 asks to show that if $(X,A)$ is a pair with the [homotopy extension property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_extension_property), then the retraction $r:X\times I\rightarrow Y=X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$ can be upgraded to a deformation retraction. This part I get.

But then the exercise ends by asking me to show the proof of proposition 0.18 now works for $(X,A)$, where the proof is given for CW complexes in the text. To recall what this proof looks like, we have two homotopic maps $f,g:A\rightarrow B$. A homotopy for these, $F:A\times I\rightarrow B$, is used to build the adjunction space $(X\times I)\cup_F B$. The proof then uses the deformation retraction of $X\times I$ to $Y$ to get a deformation retraction of $(X\times I)\cup_F B$ to $X\cup_f B$.

But I can't seem to make this work. Clearly there is a deformation retraction of $(X\times I)\cup_F B$ to a subspace $Z$. I don't see why this is homeomorphic to $X\cup_f B$ though. There is an obvious diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\sqcup B @>{i}>> (X\times I)\sqcup B\\
@VVV @VVqV \\
X\cup_f B @>>> Z\subset (X\times I)\cup_F B
\end{CD}$$

To conclude the bottom arrow is a homeomorphism however would require $qi$ to be a quotient map. For that to be true, then I would need to show for $C\subset Z$, if $(qi)^{-1}(C)$ is closed, then $C$ is closed in $Z$. Unraveling this, we have $q^{-1}(C)=S\sqcup T\subset (X\times I)\sqcup B$.  We need to find a closed subset $K\subset X\times I$ such that $K\cap Y=S$. We can write $S_0=S\cap (X\times\{0\})$, so that $S=S_0\cup F^{-1}(T)$, where $S_0$ is closed in $X\times I$ (by hypothesis) and $F^{-1}(T)$ is closed in $A\times I$.

A natural choice for $K$ is $r^{-1}(S)$. But that only works if $S$ is closed in $Y$, and I don't see why that needs to be true. In fact, I think this is the crux of the problem: **why would $S_0\cup F^{-1}(T)$ be closed in $Y$?**

Hatcher acknowledges the topological subtlety of 0.18's proof in the [errata](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT-errata.pdf) (bottom of first page). In fact, this line of reasoning is similar to showing the restriction $q:Y\sqcup B\rightarrow Z$ is a quotient map. This **is** true, but is easier because we get $S$ is closed in $Y$ by hypothesis.

So, does the proof of proposition 0.18 still work if we don't assume $A$ is closed?

Comment: If you read the errata you linked, it also states that this is corrected in an appendix in the online version. While I don't recall the detail, I remember reading it last year with your same concern, and finding, as also is stated in the errata, the argument for the general case too involved for any practical use. For most uses in AT, as Hatcher says, $A$ will be closed, and we will all rejoice.

Comment: @Evaristo: yes thanks! I see now that the general argument was moved to Proposition A.18, whose proof shows the set I asked about is indeed closed in $Y$.

Comment: @SteveD You should now write an official answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to exercise 0.26. Below $(X,A)$ is a pair with the homotopy extension property, and I'll write $Y=X\times\{0\}\cup A\times I$. The HEP implies there's a retraction $r:X\times I\rightarrow Y$.

###### $(X\times I, Y)$ has the HEP as well

Let $L$ be the "lower left" half of the boundary of $I\times I$, and $U$ the "upper right" half of the boundary. There is a deformation retraction of $I\times I$ to $L$, given by projecting from the point $(2,2)$ in the plane. For a point $(a,b)\in I\times I$, the line from $(2,2)$ to $(a,b)$ will hit a single point of $U$ (call it $\mu(a,b)$) and a single point of $L$ (call it $\ell(a,b))$. Then we can reparameterize the segment from $U$ to $L$:
\begin{equation*}
P_{a,b}(t) = (1-t)\mu(a,b) + t\ell(a,b)
\end{equation*}
Let $q(a,b)$ be the time when this segment hits $(a,b)$: $P_{a,b}(q(a,b)) = (a,b)$.

We need a retraction from $X\times I^2$ to $X\times I\times\{0\}\cup Y\times I=X\times L\cup Y\times I^2$. Writing $(y,t)=r(x,q(a,b))$, this is given by
\begin{equation*}
(x,a,b)\mapsto (y,P_{a,b}(t))
\end{equation*}

###### $Y$ is a weak deformation retract of $X\times I$

We can define a weak deformation retraction (exercise 0.4) as
\begin{equation*}
H_t(x,s) = (r(x,t), s(1-t))
\end{equation*}

###### $X\times I$ deformation retracts to $Y$

This now follows from exercise 0.4 and corollary 0.20.

###### Proposition 0.18 holds for $(X,A)$

Just as in the proof of proposition 0.18, the deformation retraction $D_t:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ induces a deformation retraction on $(X\times I)\cup_F X_0$ to a subspace $Z$, which fits into the diagram below:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\sqcup X_0 @>{i}>> Y\sqcup X_0\\
@VVV @VV{q}V \\
X\cup_f X_0 @. Z
\end{CD}$$

Here $i(x)=(x,0)$. To follow the rest of the proof of 0.18, we want to conlude that $qi$ is a quotient map, since then there will be an induced homeomorphism between $X\cup_f X_0$ and $Z$.

Suppose $C\subset Z$ is such that $(qi)^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X\sqcup X_0$; we want to show $C$ is closed in $Z$. Let $q^{-1}(C) = S\sqcup T\subset Y\sqcup X_0$. $T$ is closed in $X_0$ and $S\cap (X\times\{0\})$ is closed in $X\times\{0\}$ by hypothesis. $S\cap (A\times I)=F^{-1}(T)$ is closed in $A\times I$ by continuity. The proof of proposition A.18 in the appendix then shows $S$ is closed in $Y$.

Thus $M=D_1^{-1}(S)\subset X\times I$ is closed, and $M\cap Y=S$. This means $M\sqcup T$ is saturated, so that $q(M\sqcup T)$ is closed. But then
\begin{align*}
    q(M\sqcup T)\cap Z &= q((M\sqcup T)\cap q^{-1}(Z))\\
    &= q((M\sqcup T)\cap (Y\sqcup B))\\
    &= q(S\sqcup T)\\
    &= C
\end{align*}
And so $C$ is closed in $Z$ as desired.